# Android actionbar background styling

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a problem changing background of my actionbar.
I am following the instructions on
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html
however this does not change anything...
My ActionBar style

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showCustom</item>
</style>
```

My main application style is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/application_background</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

And I have set that style to my application via manifest.
I have no idea what is wrong with my code.
Thanks for help

Comment: So you are using the support library in your app?

Comment: Yes I am using the support library

Comment: Try to change it to `<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">`. Does that work?

Comment: But where to change this? Isnt it just like that at the moment?

Comment: No, `Light` is added to it. Like in the developer guide

Comment: AH right, my mistake, too many hours in front of pc. It did not help, however I have found that I need to add that "android:actionBarStyle" eventho it is warned else it wont work. Thank you for help tho :)

Comment: :) I totally get that. Is it working now?